No simulators (Xcode mismatch) .Net MAUI iOS(Xcode 16.0)
I don't have any simulator running, it gives me an error of incompatibility between the mac and visual studio version...
"No simulators (Xcode mismatch)"
So I'm not able to see the iOS Simulators.
When I press play I get the incompatibility error between Visual Studio version 2022 17.11.3 and Xcode version 16.0, it suggests that I downgrade to Xcode version 15.4, because the new version does not support version 16.0.
So I just have to wait or is there a solution?

The solution is to downgrade XCode until v16 support is available from Microsoft

@Jason Ok, thank you.

They are currently working to resolving the Xcode 16 bindings for .NET 8/9 MAUI. You can follow their progress here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20802
You can check under column Apple Tools which version of Xcode is supported for the MAUI version you are targeting. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Release-Versions

For now you can download the version Xcode version 15.4 from "https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%2015" and then you can choose from the Xcode which version to run. Once you download the Xcode 15.4, open that and select Xcode 15.4. Selecting Xcode 15.4 were cleared the issue for me. 
You might need to disconnect from the Mac and reconnect to the Mac in the process.

WARNING!! DO NOT upgrade MacOS to Sequoia!!
It will not allow you to run Xcode 15.4!!!

You can upgrade to MacOS Sequoia, rename Xcode 16 to Xcode.16.0 and once you've downloaded and uncompressed Xcode 15.4 move it to the Application folder.  It won't run by clicking it (you can run it by typing it into the command line); however, it will allow Visual Studio to pair to the Mac and see the Simulators.

If you updated MacOS 15 & XCode 16 already, you should downgrade Xcode from  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%2015
then modify the "Apple SDK" path (Visual Studio -> Options -> Xamarin -> Apple SDK) e.g. "/Applications/Xcode_15.4.app"
screenshot

Do not upgrade to MacOS Sequoia, 15.4 won't work and it seems XCode 16 isn't working with at the moment, if you did, only option is to using Parallels installing previous MacOS that supports 15.4.  That worked perfect for me as now I have all macOS on parallels.
